# code for finding gaps between polygon parcels

Tags: arcobjects

i am trying to write code for finding gaps between polygons, the idea is to convert polygons to polylines and checking the attribute table, each selected segment that shows two records in the tables represent  adjacent  edge between polygons, if the segment shows only one record,it then can be considered as part of gap contour.
hope someone can help me to convert this procedure to VBA code.

Comment: That sounds like a really roundabout and error-prone way of finding gaps. Also you really shouldn't be looking to write new code in VBA anymore.